# How to insert c++ find into a while loop?

Tags: c++, while-loop, find

I use a while loop with the `find` function in **c++** but I need to use the position found like the condition of the while loop but **Visual Studio** shome me

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.SEHException' occured in Test.exe
>
> Additional information: External component has thrown an exception.

I use this code:

```
int dim=myString.length();
while (dim>=0)
{
    size_t pos1 = myString.find("<article");
    size_t pos2 = myString.find("</article>");
    std::string buf = myString.substr(pos1, pos2 - pos1 + 10);
    myString = myString.substr(pos2 + 10);
    ofstream myfile("body.txt");
    if (myfile.is_open())
    {
        myfile << myString;
        myfile.close();
    }
    else cout << "Unable to open file";

    //cout << myString << endl;
    ptree xmlTree;
    string title[1000];
    int j = 0;
    try
    {
        stringstream ss;
        ss << buf;
        read_xml(ss, xmlTree);
        const ptree & formats = xmlTree.get_child("article", empty_ptree());
        BOOST_FOREACH(const ptree::value_type & f, formats)
        {
            string at = f.first + ATTR_SET;
            const ptree & attributes = f.second.get_child("<xmlattr>", empty_ptree());
            //cout << "Extracting attributes from " << at << ":" << endl;
            BOOST_FOREACH(const ptree::value_type &v, attributes)
            {
                string first = v.first.data();
                //cout << "First: " << v.first.data() << " Second: " << v.second.data() << endl;
                if (first == "title")
                {
                    title[j] = v.second.data();
                    j++;
                }
            }
        }
        for (int a = 0; a < j; a++)
        {
            cout << title[a] << endl;
        }

    }
    catch (xml_parser_error &e) {
        cout << "Failed to read config xml " << e.what() << endl;
    }
    catch (...) {
        cout << "Failed to read config xml with unknown error" << endl;
    }
    dim = dim - pos2;
}
```

what is the problem?

Comment: Most likely one of substrings couldn't be found, so corresponding result is `std::string::npos`, with all resulting subsequences

Comment: If `myString` is empty, your code fails.

Comment: @AntonSavin and how can I resolve this problem?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie how can I modify to my code?

Comment: @Shaila check the results of `find()` and behave accordingly

Comment: @Shaila You have to check to see if the value was found.  You didn't do that, instead you assumed that it was found and kept going as if nothing is wrong.

Comment: @AntonSavin but if I use this: `if(pos2 != std::string::npos) dim=dim-myString.length();` I show the same error

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie look my comment to Anton Savin before this one

Comment: @Shaila we can't guess here as you haven't provided a [mcve]. Please read [ask] page.

Comment: @Shaila I think you should write down on paper what to do instead of guessing.  Clearly you didn't take into consideration what you should do if either string wasn't found.   That should have been part of your original design.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I know what I need to do.. I need to exit from the while loop when I finish to find all **article tag** but I don't succeed ... ps in my question I add the other code that before was identified by `//some code`

Comment: @AntonSavin I add the whole code

Comment: @Shaila What if the string doesn't contain any article tags?  Your function fails immediately.  It is at the very beginning where things go wrong.  You use `pos1` and `pos2` assuming they have "good" values when you shouldn't be making that assumption.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie so? how can I resolve it? if I insert the `if` at the beginning I don't show all article tag

Answer (score 0):

I resolve my problem thanks to the help of PaulMcKenzie. I modify my code to insert a `boolean` variable and to control if `pos1` and `pos2` find the correct `string` which are `<article` and `</article>`.

This is the code:

```
int dim = myString.length();
    boolean in=true;

while (in==true)
{
    size_t pos1 = myString.find("<article");
    size_t pos2 = myString.find("</article>");
    if (pos1 != std::string::npos && pos2 != std::string::npos)
    {
        std::string buf = myString.substr(pos1, pos2 - pos1 + 10);
        myString = myString.substr(pos2 + 10);

        ofstream myfile("body.txt");
        if (myfile.is_open())
        {
            myfile << myString;
            myfile.close();
        }
        else cout << "Unable to open file";
       //some code
       dim = dim - myString.length();
            in = true;
    }
    else
    {
            in = false;
            cout << " - - - - - - - - - - " << endl;
    }

}
```